# Return value of atoi (argv[1]) is always 0

Tags: c, argv, atoi

I'm running into a problem about return value of `atoi()`.

I want to convert the `char` in command line argument `argv[1]` into `int` type and print it out.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    //print the char in *argv[]
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
            fprintf(stdout, "Arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        i = atoi(argv[1]);      //convert char to int
        fprintf(stdout, "Int version of 1st arg: %d\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it by gcc and run it like `./a.out a b c`

Other result is correct, but the `atoi()` result always displays as

```
Int version of 1st arg: 0
```

Could you give me some suggestion on this topic?

Comment: are you specifically giving ./a.out a b c ??? or are you giving numbers like ./a.out 10 20 30

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion is that if you want to convert a string to an `int`, provide as parameter a string that can actually be converted to an `int`. Your arguments are:

```
 ./a.out a b c
```

so no ints. What did you expect? What do you think `a` converted to an `int` is?

Comment: I meant to convert char type 'a' to its decimal value 97. So I expect the output shoule be Int version of 1st arg: 97

Comment: @Takumar did you read the documentation for `atoi` beforehand?

Comment: @Takumar, Then you need to take the individual character and cast it to an integer. Keep in mind it isn't always necessarily 97.

Comment: @Takumar what you're attempting is to get the integer value of a character (not a string). Which you can do by `int x(*(argv[1]))`. And then print it as `%d`.

Comment: Thanks your response. Now, I know that the only utility of atoi() is to convert a char type '0'-'9' to its corresponding int value. I should use type cast to finish my purpose.

Comment: By the way, why the decimal value of 'a' is not always 97, could you tell me more about it? Thanks again

Comment: @Takumar well, firstly, why did you assume it's always 97? What's your source?

Comment: I just use the ASCII table as reference. So, do you mean its value is platform specific?

Comment: @Takumar Not all platforms use ASCII. Google EBCDIC.

Answer (score 3):

`atoi()` converts a char string to a number - but only if the string is a number.

If you want to print `'a'` as an ASCII value just use `%d` and `argv[1][0]`, i.e. the first character of string `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

`atoi` has no way of signalling a conversion error, such as when trying to parse `a`. Use `strtol` instead, which gives you enough information to determine whether the conversion succeeded:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char const * input = "abc";  // this could be argv[i]

char * e;

long int n = strtol(input, &e, 0);

if (*e != '\0') { /* conversion error! */ }
else            { /* n is valid        */ }
```